# Graying out Visual Basic radio

Tags: vb.net

I am making an apartment rental form using Visual Basic (Express 2010) and I need to gray out some radio buttons when another radio button is selected. Right now, the graying out itself isn't a problem, i.e. I can get the radio buttons grayed out, but not when I want it to.

I need to click on a button on the form to get the specific  radio buttons grayed out, but I want them grayed out when I click on another radio button.

Here's how I have implemented the subroutine, but they don't work like I had planned them to.

```
Private Sub grpBedrooms_CheckedChanged() Handles grpBedrooms.MouseClick

    If rdoOneBed.Checked Then
        Call EnableOneBath()
        Call DisableTwoBaths()
    End If

    If rdoOneBedDen.Checked Then
        Call EnableOneBath()
        Call DisableTwoBaths()
    End If

    If rdoTwoBeds.Checked Then
        Call EnableTwoBaths()
        Call DisableOneBath()
    End If

    grpBedrooms.Refresh()

End Sub
```

So basically, I want DisableOneBath() or DisableTwoBaths() to be activated immediately when I click on the radios rdoOneBed or rdoTwoBeds, etc.

The code for actually graying out the radios is this:

```
 Private Sub DisableTwoBaths()
    Me.rdoTwoBaths.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What does not work as expected? What is `grpBedrooms`? Are you using WPF or WinForms or something different?

Comment: Graying out itself works, but I want it to gray out when I choose one of the radio buttons in grpBedrooms. grpBedrooms is the groupbox that holds the radio buttons together. I want to form to refresh itself and gray out the other radios when I choose a new radio button. I'm a total newb, and all I can say is that I'm using Microsoft Visual Express 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ..

```
Private Sub Bedrooms_Checked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rdoOneBed.CheckedChanged, rdoTwoBeds.CheckedChanged
Dim rb as RadioButton = CType(sender,RadioButton)

if rb Is rdoOneBed then
  if rdoOneBed.Checked Then DisableTwoBaths() 
elseif rb Is rdoTwoBed then
  if rdoTwoBed.Checked Then DisableOneBath()
Endif

End Sub
```

Comment: I would leave the outer `If` away. So only check the `Checked` state of all buttons. Btw, objects of reference types have to be compared with the `Is` operator instead of `=`.